# Problem with MVC++ 2013 Redist in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, vcredist

I have big problem, I' m using Visual Studio 2019 to develop my software but in my solution I have third part library that used Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redist. In my previous version of Installer Project I include the correct Merge Module files, but now I must insert the correct file for 2013 redist.
In the original installation of visual studio I have not found the Microsoft_VC120_CRT_x64.msm, but I have found the file in Github.
After the installation of my software I have seen that in the programs list, my installer add Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redist and my software crash immediately.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/visualstudio/releases/2013/2013-redistribution-vs) you can see the list of .msm files for 2013 redist, where I can download these files to add to my Installer Project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,
I have installed Visual Studio 2013 Community and the .msm files are in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules.